# Reverse array with math.floor function in javascript

Tags: javascript

Why does my function not print the reversed array in my console?

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

function swap(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(array / 2); i++) {
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];
    array[array.length - 1 - i] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}
console.log(swap(numbers));
```

Comment: do you mean `Math.floor(array.length/2)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with this line `Math.floor(array/ 2)`. It has to be `Math.floor(array.length / 2)`

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

function swap(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(array.length / 2); i++) {
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];
    array[array.length - 1 - i] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}
console.log(swap(numbers));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in your for loop the condition is `i < Math.floor(array/2)`, but rather it should be `i < Math.floor(array.length/2)`. As `.length` is the property which has the length of the array.

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

function swap(array) {
 for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(array.length/2); i++) {
  var temp = array[i];
  array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];
  array[array.length-1-i] = temp;
 }
 return array;
}
console.log(swap(numbers));
```

Also you could also just use `.reverse()`

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
console.log(numbers.reverse());
```

Comment: Ahhhrrrgggg. Thanks so much!!